# Why is my HAAR-Cascade Model not accurate? Python + OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, haar-classifier

I am using Cascade Trainer GUI to get an XML file. I have 100 positive images and 400 negative images. The training process only took about 5 minutes, and the results are not accurate. The object I trained the model for is a small screwdriver. The resulting .xml file was only 31.5 KB. Please see image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OXux.jpg)

Also, the rectangle in the photo is quite small, let alone not accurate.

Besides adding more positive and negative images, what should I do to create a more accurate model? I eventually need to do image tracking as well. Thanks

```
#import numpy as np
import cv2
import time
"""
This program uses openCV to detect faces, smiles, and eyes. It uses haarcascades which are public domain. Haar cascades rely on
xml files which contain model training data. An xml file can be generated through training many positive and negative images. 
Try your built-in camera with 'cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)' or use any video. cap = cv2.VideoCapture("videoNameHere.mp4")
"""

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')
smile = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_smile.xml')
screw = cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascade.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

prev_frame_time, new_frame_time = 0,0
while 1:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    img = cv2.resize(img,(1920,1080))
    #faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(img, 1.5, 5)
    #eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(img,1.5,6)
  #  smiles = smile.detectMultiScale(img,1.1,400)
    screws = screw.detectMultiScale(img,1.2,3)

    new_frame = time.time()
    try:
        fps = 1/(new_frame_time-prev_frame_time)
    except:
        fps = 0
    fps = int(fps)
    cv2.putText(img,"FPS: "+str(fps),(10,450), font, 3, (0,0,0), 5, cv2.LINE_AA)

   # for (x,y,w,h) in smiles:
        #cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,69,255),2)
       # cv2.putText(img,"smile",(int(x-.1*x),int(y-.1*y)),font,1,(255,255,255),2)

    for (x,y,w,h) in screws:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,255),2)
        cv2.putText(img,"screwdriver",(int(x-.1*x),int(y-.1*y)),font,1,(255,0,255),2)
  
   # for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
       #  cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
       #  cv2.putText(img,"FACE",(int(x-.1*x),int(y-.1*y)),font,1,(255,255,255),2)
      #  roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
       # eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_color)
       # for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
          #  cv2.rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
    
    
    cv2.imshow('img',img)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break
    prev_frame_time = new_frame_time

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Most resources on the topic recommend 3000-5000 images for positive and negative each. That might very well be the reason for lower accuracy.

Some resources:

1. [Link 1 - sonots](http://note.sonots.com/SciSoftware/haartraining.html)
2. [Link 2 - opencv-user-blog](http://opencvuser.blogspot.com/2011/08/creating-haar-cascade-classifier-aka.html)
3. [Link 3 - computer vision software](http://www.computer-vision-software.com/blog/2009/06/opencv-haartraining-detect-objects-using-haar-like-features/)
4. [Link 4 - pythonprogramming.net](https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/)

Comment: EDIT: I have mostly resolved this. My main problem was that my POSITIVE images were NOT CROPPED. To get an accurate model, you need to crop each image, 1 by 1, before entering them into training. Adding more relevant negative images helped as well. The final xml file was about 43 KB with ~600 CROPPED positive images, and ~ 1200 negative images

Answer (score 0):

if your image above is a 'typical' one, then it cannot work ever, using cascades.

those need *reliable texture and pose*, your scene lacks both.

(i also guess, that you do not *really* have 100 positive images, but that you tried to "synthesize" them from a few or a single image only, proven NOT to work in real life)

dont waste more time on this.
get more (real !) images, and read up on object detection cnn's like SSD or YOLO, which are far more robust with your situation.